# How does dynamically casting Microsoft.Azure.Documents result in deserialization?

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, deserialization, azure-cosmosdb

My team was given a sample file that demonstrates how to interface with CosmosDB in C# and convert resulting `Microsoft.Azure.Document` instances into POCOs. The documents are converted like this: *(Ellipses indicate left out logic for concision)*

```cs
public Task<T> GetItemAsync<T> (...)
{

    Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(...);
    return (T)(dynamic)document;

}
```

It appears to me that `(dynamic)document` somehow serializes the document which would otherwise need to be done by specifying each JSON field individually. Seeing as how `dynamic` cast operations **cannot** be overloaded, I am at a loss as to what causes this deserialization to occur.

What am I overlooking that is preventing me from understanding this operation?

Comment: `(dynamic)document` should perform an operation similar to `(object)document`. Nothing else. The document is casted as a `dynamic` first to avoid having to write an explicit cast between type `T` and type `Document`. What is type `T` in your case? `T` has to be responsible for serializing (or deserializing) the document.

Comment: T is just a poco defined manually. No operator overloads or anything, just fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a misconception here about what is actually happening behind the scenes.

Some background first

[`ReadDocumentAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReadDocumentAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns a `DocumentResponse<Document>` which wraps a `Document` containing the read resource record.

`DocumentResponse<Document>` in turn has an [`implicit operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentresponse-1.op_implicit?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentResponse_1_op_Implicit_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentResponse__0___TDocument) that that allow it to be converted/cast to `Document`

hence

```
Document item = await client.ReadDocumentAsync<T>(...);
//replaced var for to Document for demonstrative purposes.
```

[`Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.document?view=azure-dotnet) is derived from `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

```
public class Document : Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource, System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider

// Inheritance: Object --> JsonSerializable --> Resource --> Document
// Implements: IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
```

> Represents a dynamic object, **that can have its operations bound at runtime**.

***epmhasis mine***

It is because of the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` that it is first cast to `dynamic` and then to the desired type.

Behind the scenes the dynamic resource object will try to bind the contained members of the parsed document to that of the target strongly typed object.

Saves you having to try and write an explicit conversion yourself for your desired types.

You could have also used the generic overload as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question right. The target should be to have at the end the item of type `T` received from CosmosDB collection. [Have you seen the documentation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReadDocumentAsync__1_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

```
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T> (...)
{
   var item = await client.ReadDocumentAsync<T>(...);
   return item;
}
```

... will give you the deserialized content of type `T`.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the problem. I am asking about why the code in my question works, not if there is a better way. What I have is actually provided by Microsoft support according to my team lead.